# How to remove gameobjects from a new List and reset list size back to 0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arraylist

currently I am running into an issue where I add a gameobject to a new List < Gameobject > () but when I clear the list I am unable to return the list size back to 0. I receive a Missing (Game Object) and the list size still "1".

I have tried the list.clear() method but receive size at 1 and Missing (Gameobject). I have also tried a forloop to get the count and then RemoveAt(i) Method but receive the same.

I am using Unity's Inspector to visually see this issue.

Example:

```
public GameObject Object;

public List<GameObject> ObjectList = new List<GameObject>();

public void AddObjectToList()
{
    ObjectList.Add(Object);
}

public void RemoveObjectsFromList()
{
    //Attempt 1
    ObjectList.Clear();

    //Attempt 2
    for (int i = 0; i < ObjectList.Count; ++i)
    {
        ObjectList.RemoveAt(i);
    }

}
```

Expecting to clear Game Objects from list and return List size to 0.

Comment: Have you tried re-instantiating your list in the RemoveObjectsFromList method?

Comment: You shouldnt need to do that @davedno ..  Clear would empty the list.. given that this didnt do what the OP wanted, would suggest that they wanted the objects removed too

Comment: @davedno Like this " ObjectList = new List<GameObject>(); "  ?

Comment: @BugFinder Agreed, but OP has already tried those methods so I wanted to cover the bases. Thanks.

Comment: `ObjectList` is of type `List` in your example. Is this a type you wrote, or is it a typo and it should be of type `List<GameObject>`? If so, `Clear` will remove the objects from the `List<T>`. What property are you looking at that indicates there is one item in the list?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson   I am looking at a List named "ObjectList" and the Gameobject named "Object" that is inside of ObjectList. I add the gameobject to the list in one function then in a separate function I am able to clear the list of that gameobject but the size of the list will not return to 0. It will still say the size is 1 and has a missing gameobject.

Comment: @Medlin. Yeah, but in the code you posted you have `public List ObjectList = new List();`. There is not a non-generic `List` type in C# that I'm aware of, so I'm wondering if that should be `public List<GameObject> ObjectList = new List<GameObject>`. If not, and you have the code for `List`, post it so we can see the `Clear` method. If it is supposed to be `List<GameObject>`, what are you looking at that indicates there is an item in the list? `ObjectList.Count`? `ObjectList.Capacity`? Something else altogether?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson I apologize. I see what you mean and fixed that. The editor was not showing the list and gameobject correctly. Also, to answer your question in attempt #2 it receives the ObjectList.Count. The way I am visually seeing this is in Unity's Inspector.

Comment: Well, using Attempt #2 will leave objects in the list as @BugFinder explained in their answer. `Clear` will remove all of the objects in the `List<T>` and the `Count` property will be 0 after calling it (though the `Capacity` property will be greater than 0). Unless Unity itself is somehow doing something to keep the objects in the `List<T>`, at which point I'm afraid I can't help because I don't know anything about Unity :).

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson I appreciate the help. Unfortunately, using the Clear method. still returns the count property as 1 instead of 0. Maybe an issue with Unity. Not for sure.

Comment: Clear would never leave it at 1.. something must be adding to it

Comment: I cant recreate the behavior you are seeing without something else adding to it.  Clear sets the count to 0, every time.. My list of removing objects as well as the item in the list.. also does the same, results in 0

Comment: @BugFinder I understand and was completely confused about this until I realized where I messed up. If you check the answer at the bottom it explains where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at your list removal code..

```
   for (int i = 0; i < ObjectList.Count; ++i)
    {
        ObjectList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
```

So

a list with 3 items (cos Im a little lazy)

i = 0, removes at 0.. so now you have 0 and 1..
i++

now you remove 1....  leaving 0...

You need to remove in reverse..

So for i=count-1 to 0.. if you needed say to remove gameobjects or whatever,

or .clear ..

However the fact you tried .Clear suggests maybe the "objects" need to be destroyed too?

such as

```
   for (int i = ObjectList.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Destroy(ObjectList[i]);
        ObjectList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
```

Comment: So I tried your method which clears the objects out of the list but the Size of the list still remains at 1 and does not return to 0 showing Element 0 [Missing Gameobject]. When I try re-instantiating it as a new list unfortunately nothing happens.

Comment: how are you checking the size? theres a difference between size and count  are you sure something isnt adding to your list?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help but I found the answer which this may have helped everyone out if I would have mentioned it before. I was working with two separate scripts. Script1 as a main controller with all the gameobjects and lists which Script 1 called the functions from Script 2 that utilized the variables from script 1.

To be able to use variables in Script 1 across all scripts they needed to be **Static**

***Issue*:**

**Incorrect:**  public List< GameObject > ObjectList = new List< GameObject >();

**Correct:** public **Static** List< GameObject > ObjectList = new List< GameObject >();

My apologies.

Comment: Wow... this has absolutely nothing then to do with your problem you asked about.

Comment: @BugFinder This will help anyone who may run into the same error but if you have a better title for this issue I can change it to best suit this problem.

Comment: Id doubt they'd find it.  Your problem was you had 2 lists and in one case were looking at the wrong one..